# sharpjs promise returns pending result

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

This might be a duplicate, but none of the answers I found, have worked for me.

I am still a beginner, but know that when working with promises, you need to do something with the result.

In the piece of code below, I created an async function that takes a base64 string, a width and height as arguments. I then handle the image through sharp. It needs a buffer or any array of an image, so I transform it using the Buffer Constructor. I then need the function to return a base64 string back (of the resized image). I need to use this smaller base64 string later to feed it to another function.

```
    const resizer = async (base64, width, height) => {
  if (!base64) {
    throw console.error("not a base64 string")
  } else {
    const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer
    let base64buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64")
    const image = sharp(base64buffer).resize({
      width: width,
      height: height,
      fit: sharp.fit.cover,
    })
    return (await image.toBuffer()).toString("base64")
  }
}

const resizedImage = resizer(base64Image, 224, 224).then((result) => {
  return result
})
console.log(resizedImage)
```

However, when I run this code, it tells me that the promise is pending, which indicates that I am not doing anything with the result. When I change 'return result' to a console.log, then it actually does print what I need, but it will also still throw the 'promise pending' to me.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong :(

Any help or pointers really welcome! :)

Comment: `const resizedImage = await resizer(base64Image,...`

Comment: I've tried this, but it's throwing a syntax error :(

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
resizer(base64Image, 224, 224).then((result) => {
  return result
})
```

it is still a Promise. So you need to `await` like:

```
const resizedImage = await resizer(base64Image, 224, 224);
console.log(resizedImage)
```

New update from the owner.

the resizer returns a Promise. so you can not console.log the result in the global context. the solution is to move console.log into then function. like:

```
resizer(base64Image, 224, 224).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  return result
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but then it's throwing a syntaxError at me: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: @Kwinten Made an update.

Comment: Yea, I had a similar result before. You're absolutely right that a Promise is returned in the function.

Your solution does work, but doesn't solve the issue where I'd have to store that result into a variable (as I have to use it later). When I save the function as a variable, it gives me the 'pending' as well as the base64 string :(

Comment: Hmm. you can export a function like :
```
function resizeImage(base64Image) { return resizer(base64Image, 224, 224) }
```

and use it like: const result = await resizeImage(base64Image);

Comment: Yea, but then I'm still getting the 'await' syntax error D: Idk what I'm doing wrong here :'(

Comment: imagine that you store the `resizeImage` in `resizer.js`. Do you import this file to anywhere? or you are using command to execute this file directly?

Comment: The plan is to have    `resizer.js` exported to the main `index.js` where it will be used to handle any images coming from a `client.js`. So, client uploads a picture, on client side, the picture is sent to backend in a base64 formatted string. In the backend, I need to resize the image, then transform it back to a base64 so that I can use that new base64 as an argument in a machine learning backend app. I hope this makes sense?